# symfony4 migrate autowire to true - get error message

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am migrating from symofony 2.7 to symfony 4.0. With success I migrated one bundle. Now I am migrating the second bundle and the error message is coming up. I don't get at all what symfony 4.0 wants from me.

If I turn on `autowire: true` this error message is coming up.

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Kernel": argument "$environment" of method "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.
```

Can somebody help me?

If I turn it off, no message is coming up.

**Update**

I registered my bundle only in bundles.php

```
App\Backend\AccountBundle\BackendAccountBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Comment: Can you paste your configuration file? At the moment it tries to autowire your Kernel.

Comment: Default from symfony4. But a update is on my question

Comment: I am more interesting in a configuration file e.g. `config/services.yaml` where you define all things about autowiring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually the Kernel is added to the Service Container as a so called *synthetic* service, meaning it's not generated by the DI-container from configuration. Rather the id is set and then the previously configured service is just added to the container. It seems rather odd that your bundle's container wants to create a new kernel here. So I would check where and how you want to access the kernel in any of the bundle's services and whether you actually want to pass in the kernel and not something else. If you do you might want to check the Service Container-documentation on synthetic services.

As to the error itself. Symfony's autowiring often falls flat when you have services that require parameters like with the Kernel:

```
public function __construct(string $environment, bool $debug) {...}
```

In these cases you have to either have a parameter defined in your `services.yaml` that matches the name of the parameter:

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    environment: prod
    debug: false
```

or you have to tell the configuration which parameters you want to have in those places.

```
App\Kernel:
    $environment: prod
    $debug: false
```

This will tell the autowiring that only the 2 arguments named `environment` and `debug` should be overwritten with the values you provide, but the rest is done via autowiring. This way you can skip the `arguments:` part of the definition and you can also skip all arguments you know are correctly set via autowiring.

For example if you have a service like this:

```
class MyService {
    public function __construct(OtherServce $service, string $someParameter) {}
}

# config/services.yaml

services:
    _defaults:
        autowiring: true

    MyService:
        $someParameter: 'someValue'
```

This is the same as explicitly writing:

```
services:
    MyService:
        class: MyService
        arguments:
            - '@OtherServce'
            - 'someValue'
```